# Use of "manifest" as an active verb

Tags: verbs, word-usage, british-english, reflexives, intransitive-verbs

Recently I completed an English creative writing exam in which I used the phrase

> files and papers manifest, as if by some unholy magic at the tray on his desk.

My teacher stated that my use of *manifest* was incorrect. She said that it should be used as "manifest themselves". Howeverm I still believe that *manifest* can be used here as an active verb. Can anyone help explain this to me?

Comment: "Manifest themselves" *is* active. This question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: What's missing is a comma after "magic".

Answer (score 4):

Collins lists the intransitive usage, but only for an extremely restricted set of subjects:

> **manifest** ... v 3. (intr) (of a disembodied spirit) to appear in visible form

WordNet doesn't include this restriction, but the example it gives is informative:

> 1. **manifest** - reveal its presence or make an appearance; "the ghost manifests each year on the same day"

Your teacher's comment is, strictly, incorrect. However, addressing the issue of style, I'd be very careful to use the intransitive version very sparingly with subjects other than spirits and illnesses — but as you're invoking a relevant metaphor here, I can't see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=manifests+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmanifests%20a%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmanifests%20a%3B%2Cc0) for "manifests a" shows many uses, such as:

> The essential nature of this inner perception of smelling reflects
>   outer odours and, by merging them together, **manifests a**
>   transcendental organ of smelling.

and

> My article definitely **“manifests" a** belief about a deity and ultimate
>   reality. “Manifests" could, instead, have a much broader content.

and

> A marriage between a woman who **manifests a** sex-linked recessive
>   trait (X'XI and a man who is not affected (XRn in each cell (see
>   Chapter 3 under ...

Ngram appears to find about 500 valid uses since 1800, not an enormous number, but enough to substantiate the claim that the usage merits inclusion in a dictionary.  ("Manifests the", if anything, appears to be even more common.)

Answer (score -1):

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/manifest) and [American Heritage](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=manifest&submit.x=22&submit.y=11), for two examples, allow for intransitive usage of *manifest*:

> *v.intr.* To become manifest; be revealed: *Depression can manifest as irritability.*

and

> '5. *intr.* (of a disembodied spirit) to appear in visible form

That said, I myself would find it distracting, both because I see the transitive usage far more often.